# Extended rule of sum/product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that both, the sum and the product principle, can be extended to more than two sets, i.e. show that:
>
> Given finite sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ which are pairwise disjoint, then $|\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} A_i| = \sum^{n}_{i=1}|A_i|$.
>
> Given finite sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$, then $|A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_n| = \prod^{n}_{i=1} |A_i|$

**Remarks:**

I mean it's obvious that both parts are true. If we have $A \cap B = \emptyset \implies |A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$, and for the rule of product $|A \times B|$ = |A| * |B|. And also the generalization with more than two sets works. But I'm having trouble in proving the statements, cause as can be seen in the problem description is asks me to prove it.

**EDIT:**

Induction base, for $n = 2$, we have $A \cap B = \emptyset \implies |A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$, which holds. Now imagine that the induction holds for some $n$, and we want to show that it holds for $n+1$, we will have $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n \cap = \emptyset \implies |\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} A_i| = \sum^{n}_{i=1}|A_i|$.

Comment: Try to do it by induction.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Can you check my edit for the first part and tell me whether it is correct, and what to change or not?

Comment: You don't really use the induction (The induction base is correct, though). You have $\vert\left(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right)\cup A_{n+1}\vert$. By induction base, it is equal to $|\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}|+|A_{n+1}|$. Now, because you suppose it is true for $n$, you can conclude.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Got it, if you can write it as an answer, I can accept it. Plus it will be useful to someone other who will check the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sum.

We consider the $A_{i}$'s pairwise disjoint.

**Induction base**. For $n=1$, you have $|A_{1}|=|A_{1}|$, obviously. For $n=2$, you know by a previous result that $|A_{1}+A_{2}|=|A_{1}|+|A_{2}|$

**Induction step**. We suppose that the property holds for $n$ and we prove it for $n+1$. We have $$|\cup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_{i}|=\vert\left(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right)\cup A_{n+1}\vert$$ By induction base ($n=2$), it is equal to $|\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}|+|A_{n+1}|$. Now, because you suppose it is true for $n$, $|\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|A_{i}|$, so that 
$$\left\vert\cup_{i=1}^{n+1}A_{i}\right\vert=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|A_{i}|+|A_{n+1}|=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}|A_{i}|$$

> Product.

**Induction base**. For $n=1$, you have $|A_{1}|=|A_{1}|$, obviously. For $n=2$, you know by a previous result that $|A_{1}\times A_{2}|=|A_{1}|\cdot|A_{2}|$

**Induction step**. We suppose that the property holds for $n$ and we prove it for $n+1$. We have $$\left\vert A_{1}\times A_{2}\times\cdots\times A_{n+1}\right\vert=\left\vert (A_{1}\times A_{2}\times\cdots\times A_{n})\times A_{n+1}\right\vert$$
By induction base ($n=2$), we have 
$$\left\vert (A_{1}\times A_{2}\times\cdots\times A_{n})\times A_{n+1}\right\vert=\left\vert (A_{1}\times A_{2}\times\cdots\times A_{n})\right\vert\cdot \left\vert A_{n+1}\right\vert$$
And by induction step
$$\left\vert (A_{1}\times A_{2}\times\cdots\times A_{n})\right\vert\cdot \left\vert A_{n+1}\right\vert=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}|A_{i}|\right)\cdot |A_{n+1}|=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}|A_{i}|$$